# Applying MPSImageGaussianBlur with depth data

Tags: swift, core-image, metalkit, ciimage, metal-performance-shaders

I am trying to create an imitation of the portrait mode in Apple's native camera.

The problem is, that applying the blur effect using `CIImage` with respect to depth data, is too slow for the live preview I want to show to the user.

My code for this is mission is:

```
func blur(image: CIImage, mask: CIImage, orientation: UIImageOrientation = .up, blurRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let start = Date()
    let invertedMask = mask.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert")
    
    let output = image.applyingFilter("CIMaskedVariableBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputMask" : invertedMask,
                                                                                    "inputRadius": blurRadius])
    
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: image.extent) else {
        return nil
    }
    let end = Date()
    let elapsed = end.timeIntervalSince1970 - start.timeIntervalSince1970
    print("took \(elapsed) seconds to apply blur")
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation)
}
```

I want to apply the blur on the GPU for better performance. For this task, I found this implementation provided by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalImageFilters/Listings/MetalImageFilters_ImageFilters_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017535-MetalImageFilters_ImageFilters_swift-DontLinkElementID_5).

So in Apple's implementation, we have this code snippet:

```
/** Applies a Gaussian blur with a sigma value of 0.5.
 This is a pre-packaged convolution filter.
 */
class GaussianBlur: CommandBufferEncodable {
    let gaussian: MPSImageGaussianBlur

    required init(device: MTLDevice) {
        gaussian = MPSImageGaussianBlur(device: device,
                                    sigma: 5.0)
    }

    func encode(to commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer, sourceTexture: MTLTexture, destinationTexture: MTLTexture) {
        gaussian.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                    sourceTexture: sourceTexture,
                    destinationTexture: destinationTexture)
    }
}
```

How can I apply the depth data into the filtering through the Metal blur version? Or in other words - how can I achieve the first code snippets functionality, with the performance speed of the second code snippet?

Comment: Did you find a good way to do this with MPS? As far as I can tell, this could be done by applying the `CIFilter` chain to a `CIImage` and rendering it to a `MTKView` with a metal-backed `CIContext`, or just writing custom shaders. I'm working on something similar with depth filters, so would love an update.

Comment: Hey Michael, sorry but as of now I don’t have any update regarding this

Comment: Ah well, thanks anyway. FYI for the time being, I have had pretty good success rendering a filtered `CIImage` to an `MTKView`, with pretty much real-time performance..

Comment: Good to hear! Learning some MTK myself right now. I guess there is no escape learning Metal deeply in order to achieve tasks like in this question

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking you need to get `currentDrawable` first in `draw(in view: MTKView)` method. Implement `MTKViewDelegate`

```
func makeBlur() {
    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()
    
    selfView.mtkView.device = device
    selfView.mtkView.framebufferOnly = false
    selfView.mtkView.delegate = self
    
    let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
    if let image = self.backgroundSnapshotImage?.cgImage, let texture = try? textureLoader.newTexture(cgImage: image, options: nil) {
        sourceTexture = texture
    }
}

func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    if let currentDrawable = view.currentDrawable,
       let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() {
           let gaussian = MPSImageGaussianBlur(device: device, sigma: 5)
           gaussian.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: sourceTexture, destinationTexture: currentDrawable.texture)
           commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
           commandBuffer.commit()
    }
}
```